# Alert on transition from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some trouble implementing specific transition behaviour. 
I have two activities, and when I start Activity2  from Activity1,  I want Activity2 to pop up an AlertDialogue with some text it took from Activity1 (I use SharedPreferences);

basically, how do I say to Activity2 --- if you were called by this specific Activity1, please pop up an Alert if not - start with you basic layout.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data on intent of activity for that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("POP_UP_TEXT", "bla bla");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the onCreate Activity of Activity2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("POP_UP_TEXT");
   // do what you nedd here
}
```

Hope it'll help. You should have a look at [Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)